# Oracle Same Query return Different Result on Different Connection (Uncommit Transaction)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 oracle Connections using **same Query** but returning different results :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss' ) myDateTime,
t.*
FROM TMI_ISD_AUDIT_TRAIL t
WHERE NVL(USER_ID,'') LIKE '%'
AND NVL(Action,'') LIKE '%'
AND NVL(success,'') LIKE '%%'
AND TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd' ) LIKE '%'
AND rownum <100
```

Query return 1 row
[image]

Query return 2 row
[image]

Connection 1 IP :
[image]
Connection 2 IP :
[image]

How to check underlying uncommitted transaction?

Comment: The only way I can imagine this is happening is if the underlying data is actually changing in between the two queries.

Comment: No, Sir. No transaction so far..

Comment: If you remove the `rownum` condition it returns the same transactions?

Comment: Remove rownum return same Sir

Comment: What is the meaning of third user, Arnaud?

Comment: what oracle version are you using?

Comment: If you query SELECT * in both connections, have you these 2 lines in each result ?

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: SELECT * return same result sir

Comment: Try to re-build your query by adding one element by one, and see when the results is different.

Comment: I have did it with copy paste, the query is same. This happened not just once. I have same experience.. but no clue

Comment: Yes this seems weird. Which the lessons of history suggest means it is not happening the way you think it is. Unfortunately we're reduced to guessing what the explanation might be. I agree with @TimBiegeleisen that an uncommitted transaction seems the likeliest explanation. Your screenshots appear to have two tabs, showing `TMI_ISD_AUDIT_TRAIL`  for each of the connections: do they reflect the different outcomes of the worksheet queries?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Last day, this case happened again. Then I am tired and close connection BIZ_UAT. And then one popup showing to commit changes. When I click yes, then changes stored at DB. 
How to check the pending commit transaction happened on SQL Developer, Sir?

Answer (score 0):

With [Oracle 12](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149796/query-with-rownum-returns-differents-rows-on-every-execution) you can use [fetch first](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqljoffsetfetch.html) instead of ROWNUM for ordering

> ROWNUM is evaluated before ORDER BY, that is not how ROWNUM should be used.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss' ) myDateTime,
t.*
FROM TMI_ISD_AUDIT_TRAIL t
WHERE NVL(USER_ID,'') LIKE '%'
AND NVL(Action,'') LIKE '%'
AND NVL(success,'') LIKE '%%'
AND TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd' ) LIKE '%'
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mi:ss' )
FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

> The fetch first clause, which can be combined with the result offset clause if desired, limits the number of rows returned in the result set. The fetch first clause can sometimes be useful for retrieving only a few rows from an otherwise large result set, usually in combination with an ORDER BY clause. The use of this clause can give efficiency benefits. In addition, it can make programming the application simpler.

Comment: I have tried it and still not changed. first query return 2 and other query return 1.

Comment: @toha why do you use `LIKE '%'` conditions?

Comment: @toha by the way, `where nvl(action,'') like '%'` is a complicated way of writing `where action is not null`.

Comment: yes but there is no null record at the queried data